# Show that this function is continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

In this case i'm struggling to show that the partial derivatives with respect to x are continuous. The answers always brush over how you determine it like it trivial so i think i'm missing something. I understand that that you only need to consider the case of x=0 and y=0 for the following example and show that the limit is equal to the partial derivative at (0,0) but i'm struggling to do this for the following example. So I was wondering if somebody would be able to demonstrate the proof to show that the x component of the partial derivative is continuous at (0,0)?

$$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\:\text{if $(x,y) \not= (0,0)$;}\\ 
0,\:\text{if  $(x,y)=(0,0)$;} \end{array}\right.$$

$$\begin{cases} \dfrac {\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)= \dfrac{x^3y^2+2xy^4}{\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}}\\
\dfrac {\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim \limits_{h\to 0}\left(\dfrac {f(h,0)}{h}\right)=0\end{cases}$$

Note: I have changed the example. This one should have both continuous partial derivatives with them both equal to 0 at (0,0).

Comment: $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h^3/h}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} h = 0$$ What is $f$?

Comment: Sorry, just put it in then

Comment: Okay, so the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ is a typo, should have been $\frac{h^3/h^2}{h}$. Nevertheless, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is _not_ continuous at $(0,0)$. Try showing that instead.

Comment: Okay cheers. I changed the example to one that does have continuous partial derivatives at zero now. Thankyou for that.